# slider counter length two digit number

Tags: javascript, jquery

im using supersized jquery plugin for fullscreen slider, and there is a slider counter and its good but i want display numbers in two digit form like 01,02...09,10.

link for documentation : [supersized-documentation](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#variables_docs)

i tried some code, but it was not working

```
if(vars.slide_current.length > 9){
    return n > 9 ? "" + n: "0" + vars.slide_current.length;
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: What is the value of `n` in your code?

Comment: well i searched here and tried edit code what ive found here, but it wasnt working

Comment: It looks like the docs say to use `vars.current_slide`, not `vars.slide_current`. Could that be an issue?

Comment: Nope, its still not working, doesnt exist any code that convert any numbers in selected div to that look?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your if-statement is set up so that you will only return the formatted string if `vars.slide_current.length` is greater than 9, which is not what you want. You can do either a basic:

```
var n = vars.slide_current.length;
return n > 9 ? '' + n : '0' + n;
```

which will return the formatted number n, or:

```
var n = vars.slide_current.length;
if (n < 10) {
    return '0' + n;
} else {
    return '' + n;
}
```

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4r9g/2/) shows version 1.

**Edit**: After looking at your site, I think this will help:

Instead of doing:

```
if (vars.slide_current.length) {
    a(vars.slide_current).html(vars.current_slide + 1)
}
```

Try:

```
if (vars.slide_current.length) {
    var n = vars.current_slide + 1; // + 1 because of what your old code shows.
    var numToDisplay = n > 9 ? '' + n : '0' + n;
    a(vars.slide_current).html(numToDisplay);
}
```

Or, the basic way:

```
if (vars.slide_current.length) {
    var numToDisplay;
    var n = vars.current_slide + 1; // + 1 because of what your old code shows.
    if (n < 10) {
        numToDisplay = '0' + n;
    } else {
        numToDisplay = '' + n;
    }
    a(vars.slide_current).html(numToDisplay);
}
```

Hopefully this works for you!

Comment: hello again, how can i this write like jquery?

Comment: Technically because jQuery is a library written in Javascript, you can run this code in series with jQuery. In [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4r9g/5/), you can see that the `$(document).ready(function() {` code is in jQuery, but the script from above is plain javascript. Does this make sense?

Comment: yeah i understand, thank you very much, but here's my link to page, i have purchased theme ftom tf, but the slider is from plugin, http://richiestudio.6f.sk/wp/wordpress/
as you may see, its still not working, i dont know what i need to do, in js is this, but i dont know how to edit this...


if (vars.slide_current.length) {
    a(vars.slide_current).html(vars.current_slide + 1)
   }

Comment: Clarification question - Are you trying to get the numbers in the top right [1/2] and [2/2] to be [01/02] and [02/02]?

Comment: exactly, but with simple script " $('#slidenumber').text(function(i,txt) { var c = parseInt(txt, 10); return (c<10) ? "0"+c : c; });, it was working just for first slide, for numbers all slides it was working because that is static number,but in time when slide was changed, number was again 2 and not 02, i add it to theme, then you can see.

Comment: Check to see if my updated answer will help. I will be back in a few hours to continue helping if need be :)

Comment: first of all, thank you for all your patience and help, but its still not working, now it shows number 13, i dont know why but if i add on last line a(vars.slide_current.**length**).html, it shows again the same result.

Comment: Odd. My next move would be to use `console.log()` to find out what the values of `vars.slide_current.length` and `numToDisplay` are - right before the line `a(vars.slide_content).html(numToDisplay);`. This will help to debug the code. Have you used `console.log()` before?

Comment: Hello again, ive added console log code to debugging, it seems that vars.slide_current.length shows number 12 and numToDisplay 13.

Comment: Okay, I think that was my bad. I updated my answer - I think the problem is that you need to use `vars.current_slide` which updated. Hopefully this one will work? Also, while you're at it, see what your variable `vars.current_slide` is instead of `vars.slide_current.length`.

Comment: And again huuuuuuuge thank you :-). Im really happy. I owe you beer, you are awesome. Thank you again

Comment: Rad! Lemme know if you have other questions in the future! Also would you mind accepting this answer?

Comment: yeah i want to, but i dont have 15 reputation

Comment: Gotcha, no worries then!